# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE - unable to start development server

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm following React Native's walktrough for getting startet with app creating, but when i get to
"npm start" the localhost server shuts down after one second and i get these errors in cmd:

```
C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject>npm start

> @ start C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject
> expo start

Starting project at C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
error Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(.*\\__fixtures__\\.*|node_modules[\\\]react[\\\]dist[\\\].*|website\\node_modules\\.*|heapCapture\\bundle\.js|.*\\__tests__\\.*)$/: Unterminated character class
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)
    at blacklist (C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js:34:10)
    at getBlacklistRE (C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\loadMetroConfig.js:66:59)
    at getDefaultConfig (C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\loadMetroConfig.js:82:20)
    at load (C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\tools\loadMetroConfig.js:118:25)
    at Object.runServer [as func] (C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\server\runServer.js:82:58)
    at Command.handleAction (C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:23)
    at Command.listener (C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Command.parseArgs (C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject\node_modules\commander\index.js:651:12)
Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
```

The code log is:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.1
3 info using node@v12.13.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prestart: @
6 info lifecycle @~start: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Python37\;C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python37\;C:\Users\olsta\Scripts\;C:\Users\olsta\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\bin;C:\Users\olsta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Python;C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Python\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\olsta\AppData\Local\Julia-1.2.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\olsta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\olsta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Python\Scripts\;C:\Python\;C:\Users\olsta\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Users\olsta\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject
10 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `expo start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\olsta\AwesomeProject
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.13.1
19 verbose npm  v6.12.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ start: `expo start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

And the package.json looks like:

```
{
  "_from": "expo-cli",
  "_id": "expo-cli@3.11.1",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha512-efLwUDLhn37+P06sxFzuszgRWssUVJOTlVab/w4hGYi0mYI/0weSHiZggA/NXJfdeLikZrTR7Wk5OChRPHyRiQ==",
  "_location": "/expo-cli",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "type": "tag",
    "registry": true,
    "raw": "expo-cli",
    "name": "expo-cli",
    "escapedName": "expo-cli",
    "rawSpec": "",
    "saveSpec": null,
    "fetchSpec": "latest"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#USER"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-cli/-/expo-cli-3.11.1.tgz",
  "_shasum": "ded8e248e2b08e26cb8e5ed057d9ff1927389251",
  "_spec": "expo-cli",
  "_where": "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32",
  "bin": {
    "expo": "./bin/expo.js",
    "expo-cli": "./bin/expo.js"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues"
  },
  "bundleDependencies": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/build-tools": "0.1.0-alpha.8",
    "@expo/bunyan": "3.0.2",
    "@expo/config": "^2.5.2",
    "@expo/dev-tools": "^0.9.2",
    "@expo/json-file": "^8.2.2",
    "@expo/package-manager": "^0.0.1",
    "@expo/simple-spinner": "1.0.2",
    "@expo/spawn-async": "1.5.0",
    "@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin": "1.11.0",
    "@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux": "1.11.0",
    "@expo/xdl": "57.2.1",
    "@types/cli-table": "^0.3.0",
    "@types/untildify": "^3.0.0",
    "ansi-regex": "^4.1.0",
    "axios": "0.19.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "base32.js": "0.1.0",
    "boxen": "4.1.0",
    "chalk": "2.4.1",
    "cli-table": "0.3.1",
    "commander": "2.17.1",
    "dateformat": "3.0.3",
    "delay-async": "1.2.0",
    "detect-indent": "^6.0.0",
    "detect-newline": "^3.0.0",
    "enquirer": "^2.3.2",
    "envinfo": "5.10.0",
    "es6-error": "3.2.0",
    "expo-optimize": "^0.0.3",
    "fs-extra": "6.0.1",
    "getenv": "0.7.0",
    "glob": "7.1.2",
    "indent-string": "4.0.0",
    "inflection": "^1.12.0",
    "inquirer": "5.2.0",
    "klaw-sync": "6.0.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "match-require": "2.1.0",
    "npm-package-arg": "6.1.0",
    "open": "6.3.0",
    "ora": "3.4.0",
    "pacote": "9.3.0",
    "pngjs": "3.4.0",
    "progress": "2.0.0",
    "qrcode-terminal": "0.11.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "semver": "5.5.0",
    "slash": "1.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "0.5.9",
    "split": "1.0.1",
    "targz": "^1.0.1",
    "tempy": "^0.3.0",
    "untildify": "3.0.3",
    "validator": "10.5.0",
    "wordwrap": "1.0.0"
  },
  "deprecated": false,
  "description": "The command-line tool for creating and publishing Expo apps",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@expo/babel-preset-cli": "^0.2.2",
    "@types/ansi-regex": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/dateformat": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/inflection": "^1.5.28",
    "@types/inquirer": "6.0.3",
    "@types/klaw-sync": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/npm-package-arg": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/progress": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/slash": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/split": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/wordwrap": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "pkg": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.1"
  },
  "files": [
    "build",
    "bin"
  ],
  "gitHead": "613642fe06827cc231405784b099cf71c29072df",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/tree/master/packages/expo-cli#readme",
  "keywords": [
    "expo",
    "react-native"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "build/exp.js",
  "name": "expo-cli",
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin": "1.11.0",
    "@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux": "1.11.0"
  },
  "pkg": {
    "scripts": "build/**/*.js"
  },
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/expo/expo-cli.git",
    "directory": "packages/expo-cli"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --noEmit && gulp build",
    "clean": "rm -rf build ./tsconfig.tsbuildinfo",
    "pkg": "pkg .",
    "prepare": "yarn run clean && yarn run build",
    "preversion": "node ./scripts/preversion.js",
    "start": "yarn run prepare && yarn run watch",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "watch": "concurrently \"tsc --noEmit --watch\" \"gulp watch\""
  },
  "version": "3.11.1"
}
```

Sorry for the amount of code, I'm not sure what you need to help me. Regarding similar questions:
I have tried:
Step 1: $ npm cache clean --force

Step 2: Delete node_modules by $ rm -rf node_modules folder or delete it manually by going into the directory and right-click > delete / move to trash. Also, delete package-lock.json file too.

Step 3: npm install

To start again, $ npm start
It didn't work for me, but i couldn't find the package-lock.json file in the first place.
Versions:
node.js - v12.13.1
npm - 6.12.1
expo - 3.11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with node version (12.13.1) that you are using.
Uninstall NodeJs from your system and download and install NodeJS version 12.9.0 
Then you wont face the issue that you have mentioned. I was having same problem as yours. but, it worked for me.